# how to achieve circular shape image using pdfmake in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-blob-storage, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake to generate pdf's in node.js.

```
const imageBuffer = await imageToBase64('image path'); //image from azure blob storage
const pdfData = {
    content: [
        {
          image: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageBuffer}`,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
        }
    ]
};

----rest of the pdf logic goes here----
```

Image is coming in default shape (rectangle) in the pdf.
I know that there is no 'border-radius' property in pdfmake styles. But I need to stick with pdfmake.
But I need to show the image in a round (circular) shape.
Is there any way to convert the "imageBuffer" into circular one using any npm package or someother way?

Need someone's valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to convert the "imageBuffer" into a circular one using any npm package or some other way?

You can use the `canvas` module to crop the image and the `pdfmake` module to create the PDF.

AFAIK, the **`pdfmake`** does not support rounded images out of the box. However, there are a few workarounds you can try to achieve this effect.

**Code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pdfMake = require('pdfmake');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');

async function processImage(image_url) {
  const img = await loadImage(image_url);
  const canvas = createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
  return buffer.toString('base64');
}

async function generatePDF() {
  const image_url = "your-storage-account-blob-url";
  const imageBuffer = await processImage(image_url);
  const fonts = {
  Roboto: {
    normal: 'path/to/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
    bold: 'path/to/Roboto-Bold.ttf',
    italics: 'path/to/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'path/to/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf'
  }
};
const docDefinition = {
    content: [
      {
        image: `data:image/png;base64,${imageBuffer}`,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      },
    ],
    defaultStyle: {
    font: 'Roboto'
  },
  fonts: fonts
};

// Create a PDF document
const printer = new pdfMake();
const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

// Save the PDF document to a local file
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sample.pdf'));
pdfDoc.end();
}

generatePDF();
```

The above code generates a PDF document using an image that has been cropped into a circle shape. It uses the **`canvas`** module to crop the image and the **`pdfmake`** module to create the PDF.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Still getting rectangle shape not circular shape